# Sorting rows on Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I know Silverlight is almost dead, but I have an application in Silverlight that I have to maintain till the product owner allows migrating.

I've noticed that in some DataGrids user can sort data, although I noticed that in DataGrids that have RowDetails this is not possible. Is that some limitation  of Silverlight or is there some work around?

Comment: Do the DataGrids explicitly enable or disable sorting?

Comment: Nope. Although I've tried explicitly enable through CanUserSortColumns property.As I said, just in grids with row details doesn't sort.

Comment: user 'SortMemberPath' on property so that the column will sort or implemnt the Sorting event.

Comment: That worked @user2526236 I specified the property SortMemberPath on my DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: if it has helped , please mark as answer.

Comment: you should answer. I gave you a vote on your comment. That's all I can do.

Comment: @user2526236 You should enter your comment as an answer so the original poster can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `SortMemberPath` on property so that the column will sort or implemnt the `Sorting` event.